# Makefile for .c and .cpp files does not work

Tags: makefile

I try to compile both .c and .cpp files as C++ and build it into one resulting binary. My Makefile looks like this (simplified):

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -fpermissive -DENV_EMBEDDED -I../utils/ -../usblib/include
CPPFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)

LDFLAGS  = -lmisc -lrt

PNAME=Simulator

OBJ = simulated.o \
    buffer.o \
    common.o 

all: $(OBJ)
    $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PNAME) $(OBJ)
```

When I do a "make all" it complains about "don't know how to create target "simulated.o".

CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS/CXXFLAGS should be used automatically dependent on .c/.cpp file - right? So what could be wrong in this Makefile?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) This is not about the different languages C or C++, but makefiles. Don't spam tags. 2) C is not C++ is not C! Don't compiler C code as C++ and vice-versa. Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics. If you want to use a C module in a C++ project, provide an approriate header for C++ and compile the C code as C. You are asking about an XY-problem.

Comment: Have you read the manual of make?

Comment: Was that the precise error message? The GNU Make version of that message is "don't know how to create target", and it would be useful to know which Make version you're using. Do you have a file `simulated.cpp`? The command `make -p -f/dev/null` (or similar, depending on your make) will print the 'database' of rules – search for the .cpp rule in there for possible illumination.

Comment: @Norman Gray: original error message is "make: *** Keine Regel vorhanden, um das Target »simulated.o«, benötigt von »all«, zu erstellen.  Schluss." ;-) Which means something like "no rule to create target simulated.o needed by all"

Comment: @Elmi Ah, right.  The non-internationalised version of that is 'don't know how to create target', so that might be worth searching for. Otherwise, there's nothing obviously wrong with your Makefile. If I were you, I'd first resolve the C/C++ confusion that @Olaf mentions, then study the output of `make -p` and `make -d`. Does this precise makefile fail when run at the command line? Your source is called `simulated.cpp`, yes?

Comment: @Norman Gray finally I found it - the file simulated.c simply was not in place :-D I know, mixing C and C++ is a bit strange but in this case can be explained, the C-files are from a firmware of a microcontroller, the CPP-files are wxWidgets UI components and all together are a simulator of the firmware running on a normal PC. None of the components can be moced to C or C++, all have to stay what they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason for my problem, it had nothing to do with that funny C/CPP mixture. Instead of this the file simulated.c simply was not in place :-D I know, mixing C and C++ is a bit strange but in this case can be explained, the C-files are from a firmware of a microcontroller, the CPP-files are wxWidgets UI components and all together are a simulator of the firmware running on a normal PC. None of the components can be moved to C or C++, all have to stay what they are.